# Chunk SMS into SMSes of size 30 characters

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

The problem statement is as follows -

```
There is a text messaging service.It provides with an API to send SMSes to a user, 
but they can be at most 30 characters long. 
Also it doesn't guarantee the order in which the messages will be received.


You have to build a function which splits the text in chunks so that it can 
be sent in multiple messages. Each chunk has to be :
- upto 30 characters long
- no word should be split in the middle
- each chunk has to have its order suffixed in the form of '(k/n)' 
  e.g. "this is the first chunk (1/2)", "this is the second chunk (2/2)"
- if the text provided to the function is within 30 characters limit, 
  no ordering should be suffixed

Input/Output Format 
Each test case consists of a single line of words. Words are space 
separated. Any other character other than space is considered part of 
the word. For each test case, output the minimum number of chunks C 
required to fit the entire SMS. 

Restrictions
1 <=C<= 99; Input will be such that C remain in this mentioned limit 
if your algorithm is optimal. No word will have a length that does 
not fit in a single chunk (even after considering the suffix).

Sample Input: 
The best lies are always mixed with a little truth 
There is no creature on earth half so terrifying as a truly just man!!!!!
You know nothing, Jon Snow 

Sample Output 
3
3
1

Explanation: 
In first case, we will have to split as below 

The best lies are always (1/3)
mixed with a little (2/3)
truth (3/3)

First line is fully utilised with 30 characters in it. 
Second line has 25 characters but if we try to fit last word in this line, 
it becomes 31 characters. 'mixed with a little truth (2/2) 
Hence we must split into 3 parts as above.
```

My approach -> was more around finding the approximate number of chunks first and then expanding on it but that didn't work. I was wondering is it even possible to first calculate how many chunks will be required mathematically or do we actually have to build chunks and see but then how do we build chunks without knowing 'n' of 'k/n'?

Comment: To me this can be solved easily using greedy approach. Just need to be deft with character array manipulation. You don't need to know number of chunks ahead. Just make the character as 'n' before the last character i.e. ')'. Keep updating the value of a counter of chunks and replace that 'n' with the character value of the counter after the whole string is processed. Max chunks is 99 so allot 2 spaces for that in the line even if there are less than 10 chunks. That way you are guaranteed you are not breaking 30 char limit of a chunk.

Comment: @SomeDude It says *if your algorithm is optimal*, which leads me to suspect that there will be a test sample where it is necessary to take into account the variable length of the suffix.

Comment: @SomeDude This approach will give a _valid_ partition, but the problem asks for the _minimum_ number of chunks.

Comment: yes, suffix length is what is tricky here.. an edge case can be.. u might start with 9 chunks .. so then u add (1/9), (2/9), (3/9) etc but then by 1 or 2 characters coz u cant break a word.. u end up with 10 chunks and now all suffixes need to be changed and all chunks need to be changed

Comment: What are the input restrictions? How many test cases and maximum length of test case? Why not just binary search the optimal number of chunks for each case?

Comment: @user58697 I believe greedy approach would yield minimum number of chunks. Just keep grabbing until you hit 30 char limit with all valid words as a constraint.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I believe the suffix should part always take a constant amount of space => 1 space char, 1 '(' char, 2 digits ( in case number of chunks is greater than 10 - note that max chunks is 99 ), 1 ')' char => total 5 chars for the suffix. this is constant - with in the remaining 25 chars you need to fit the valid words. Edge case is that if there is only 1 chunk and there is a word left out , see if it can be fit into the suffix space i.e. 5 chars.

Comment: @SomeDude I am afraid you miss the important part: `(k/n)` is part of those 30 chars.

Comment: @user58697 I accounted for the suffix in that 30 char limit, see my other comment

Comment: @SomeDude If I understand correctly, you always allocate 2 chars for `n`. If there is less than 10 chunks, it only need 1 char, and there might be a better arrangement. Of course the problem becomes much more interesting without `C <= 99` restriction.

Comment: @SomeDude The length of the suffix changes when it goes from "(9/99)" to "(10/99)", neither of which is the same length as "(9/9)".

Answer (score 1):

You have to know *n* to be able to know how many words can be put in each chunk because that depends on *n*.

Even if *n* is expressed in base 99 so that it only takes one character, you still need to examine the length of every word individually.

I have a suspicion that the *optimal* distribution of words between chunks is not the simple method of putting words (and spaces) into lines until the next item won't fit: it could be better to make some smaller chunks somewhere earlier to enable better packing later. However, this is not the [cutting stock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) because the order must be preserved.

By the simple method, I mean packing the words in assuming there are less than ten chunks, and if not then start again based on there being less than 100 chunks, for example in VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Function NumberLength(n As Integer) As Integer
        Return If(n < 10, 1, 2)
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim msg = "Escobazos tu dios pisan amor sus el las grupos se y no de los pulso mudas muerte mi inocentes vilo los las bajaba viciosa tierra de amor horizonte la se deja de tierra heridas ni los la es los recodos horizonte diminutas la de es nube talco hombrecillo de piel los se escobazos nadadora de bajo consume las se con ni las en por que donde tierra es sillas el de de que latido viva lo a grupos torre escaleras desnudo dolor me a la la quedo que sepultura signos criaturas de desnudo subía la húmedo desnuda latido nube quedo de la el nadadora el cielo dolor arroyo escobazos quedo donde de amor venas el viva poniendo desangradas torre que resonancia los fría ansioso el de subía el tierra todo se ansioso manteles por amor amor con de el quemadas resonancia con mujer el y que luna los bajaba quedo los yo a alegrísima de ilesa huido el mi que los se bajo la hombrecillo luna en de vilo es de el aire despenada que latido aire para sus horizonte todo muelles heridas viva hule tierra para huido de las a los llenando los que por húmedo tránsito tierra la la aire olvidando recodos de de la ligeros los término por luna bajaba tierra llenando del al que bajo de que de a pupila mueven que grupos se tránsito los ciudades de de nino mármol vuelve lenguas se los pisotean la vengo con faraón tránsito ballenas la se los tierra del escaleras de tierra nunca lenta se musgos que desgarrados la de desgarrados la imperturbable la resonancia y duro subía tierra me mi de talco escaleras el duro los desangradas sus buscando desangradas de pies algodón golondrina por que las no larga con diana que el en imperturbable de los luna al la huevos muertos las los las larga para borrachos de el aire los la bajo tierra fría talco los los comida en llanura en en los todo que en olvidando es de el de tu la de los muerte los las de que húmedo llenando de los pasan los hombrecillo se duro lenta ballenas ninos hule la con a la tierra por gustada es y se tierra amor las recientes manteles tierra de para signos el es un diana es del dios es imperturbable de consume de muelles luna para al nube tierra bajo apariencia encuentro es diminutas"
        Dim nPart = 1
        Dim nPartsTotal = 1 'assume 9 or less parts
        Dim nPartsTotalLength = 1
        Dim maxPartLength = 30

        If msg.Length <= maxPartLength Then
            Console.WriteLine("1")
            Console.ReadLine()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim words = Regex.Split(msg, "( )")

        Dim suffixLength = 5 ' up to 9 parts

        Dim pos = 0
        Dim nWord = 0

        Dim thisPart As New StringBuilder
        Dim partText As New List(Of String)

        While nWord < words.Count()
            suffixLength = 3 + NumberLength(nPart) + nPartsTotalLength
            If pos + suffixLength + words(nWord).Length <= maxPartLength Then
                pos += words(nWord).Length
                nWord += 1
                thisPart.Append(words(nWord - 1))
            Else
                partText.Add(thisPart.ToString())
                pos = 0
                nPart += 1
                nPartsTotal += 1
                thisPart.Clear()

                If nPartsTotal > 9 AndAlso nPartsTotalLength = 1 Then
                    ' start again knowing that there are more than 9 parts required
                    nPartsTotalLength = 2
                    nPart = 1
                    nPartsTotal = 1
                    nWord = 0
                    partText.Clear()
                End If
            End If

        End While

        If thisPart.Length > 0 Then
            partText.Add(thisPart.ToString())
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(nPartsTotal)
        Console.WriteLine(New String("|"c, maxPartLength)) ' show max length

        For i = 1 To partText.Count()
            Console.WriteLine($"{partText(i - 1)}({i}/{nPartsTotal})")
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

That happens to generate 99 chunks. The question doesn't ask for the output of the actual chunks - that part of the example code is there to have a look in case it is obvious where a different alogorithm could do better.

Answer (score 0):

It was rather simpler. I started with trying to find the number of chunks first and that is where it went wrong. Andrew's solution is correct.

I am attaching my code in JavaScript(just for reference)

```
function splitSMSIn10Chunks(string){
    let parts = string.split(' ');
    let suffix = '(x/y)';
    let chunks = 0;
    let currentChunk = '';
    for(let i=0;i<parts.length;i++){ 

        if((currentChunk.length+1+parts[i].length+suffix.length)<=30){
            currentChunk = currentChunk + parts[i] + " ";
        }else{            
            currentChunk = currentChunk + suffix;
            currentChunk = parts[i]+" " ;
            chunks++;
        }        
        if(i==parts.length-1){
            //Last chunk
            currentChunk = currentChunk + suffix;
            chunks++;
        }
        if(chunks==10) return -1;
    }
    return chunks;
};

function splitSMSIn99Chunks(string){

    let parts = string.split(' ');
    let suffix = '(x/yy)';
    let chunks = 0;
    let currentChunk = '';
    for(let i=0;i<parts.length;i++){  

        if((currentChunk.length+1+parts[i].length+suffix.length)<=30){
            currentChunk = currentChunk + parts[i] + " ";
        }else{            
            currentChunk = currentChunk + suffix;
            currentChunk = parts[i]+" " ;
            chunks++;
            if(chunks==9){
                suffix = '(xx/yy)';
            }
        }        

        if(i==parts.length-1){
            //Last chunk
            currentChunk = currentChunk + suffix;
            chunks++;
            console.log(currentChunk);
        }
    }
    return chunks;
};

let sms = "The best lies are always mixed with a little truth The best lies are always mixed with a little truth The best lies are always mixed with a little truth The best lies are always mixed with a little truth";

let chunksRequired = splitSMSIn10Chunks(sms);
if(chunksRequired==-1){
    console.log(splitSMSIn99Chunks(sms));
}else{
    console.log(chunksRequired);
}
```

It can be done in 1 function also but to keep it simpler and easier to read, I have created two separate functions.